# Projecting specific fields present inside an array, based on the value of some other field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Overview :**

The documents, that I'm working upon, have two nested arrays in them - `contentMetaData` & `text_content`.
Within `contentMetaData`, we have the `text_content` and `content_flag`. Based on the value of the `content_flag`, I need to hide specific field within the `text_content`.

**Requirement :**

- If the `content_flag` is true, `text_content` should have a single child - the `text_note`.
- If the `content_flag` is false, `text_content` should have a single child - the `text_description`.
- The structure and other details need to be preserved.
- Documents **SHOULD NOT** be updated; the values need to be only hidden during projection.

**Version Used :** Mongo 2.6

**Sample Document :**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56f8dd19e4b0365115927b0f"),
  "contentId": "cbc91805-2faa-4eff-8f84-02547173c152",
  "contentMetaData": [
    {
      "_id": "1574b58f-b7fa-4cd5-b34f-98beeb657c97",
      "name": "text_content",
      "attributes": [],
      "children": [
        {
          "_id": "97340ecf-fdbd-41e5-a6b2-01cc542f16ee",
          "name": "text_note",
          "value": "abc",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "attributes": [],
          "children": [],
          "noOfChildren": 0,
          "positionIndex": 1
        },
        {
          "_id": "19c5a3fb-54a2-4368-a89d-ea1d2554402d",
          "name": "text_description",
          "value": "def",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "attributes": [],
          "children": [],
          "noOfChildren": 0,
          "positionIndex": 2
        }
      ],
      "noOfChildren": 2,
      "positionIndex": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "4e8ef7c9-cffd-4b36-9109-89b263dff3c8",
      "name": "content_flag",
      "value": "true",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "attributes": [],
      "children": [],
      "noOfChildren": 0,
      "positionIndex": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample Output :**

```
{
  "_id":  ObjectId("56f8dd19e4b0365115927b0f"),
  "contentId": "cbc91805-2faa-4eff-8f84-02547173c152",
  "contentMetaData": [
    {
      "_id": "1574b58f-b7fa-4cd5-b34f-98beeb657c97",
      "name": "text_content",
      "attributes": [],
      "children": [
        {
          "_id": "97340ecf-fdbd-41e5-a6b2-01cc542f16ee",
          "name": "text_note",
          "value": "abc",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "attributes": [],
          "children": [],
          "noOfChildren": 0,
          "positionIndex": 1
        }
      ],
      "noOfChildren": 2,
      "positionIndex": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "4e8ef7c9-cffd-4b36-9109-89b263dff3c8",
      "name": "content_flag",
      "value": "true",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "attributes": [],
      "children": [],
      "noOfChildren": 0,
      "positionIndex": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I attempted using `$map` but it didn't work. I tried using `$unwind`, but was unable to `$push` the data back, in the desired format.

Sample Mongo Code :

```
db.content.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        contentId: 1,
        contentMetaData: 1
        tempMetaData: "$contentMetaData"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$contentMetaData"
},
{
    $match: {
        "contentMetaData.name": "content_flag"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        contentId: 1,
        contentMetaData: "$tempMetaData",
        content_flag_value: "$contentMetaData.value"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        contentId: 1,
        contentMetaData: 1,
        tempMetaData: "$contentMetaData",
        content_flag_value: 1
    }
},
{
        $unwind: "$contentMetaData"
},
{
        $match: {
                "contentMetaData.name": "text_content"
        }
},
{
        $project: {
                _id: 1,
                contentId: 1,
                contentMetaData: 1,
                tempMetaData: "$contentMetaData",
                content_flag_value: 1,
                text_content : "$contentMetaData.children",
                temp_text_content: "$text_content"
        }
},
{
        $unwind: "$text_content"
},
{
        $group:{
            _id:"$_id",
            contentId:{$first:"$contentId"},
            text_content:
            {$max:
                {$cond: 
                    [
                        {$eq: ["$content_flag_value", "true"]},
                        {$cond:
                            [{$or:[
                                {$eq: ["$text_content.name","wk_link_url"]},
                                {$eq: ["$text_content.name","wk_link_description"]}
                            ]},
                            "$text_content",
                            null]
                        },
                        null
                    ]
                }
            },
            contentMetaData:{$first:"$contentMetaData"}
        }
},
{
        $group:{
            _id:"$_id",
            contentId:{$first:"$contentId"},
            contentMetaData:{$push:{"text_content":"$text_content"}}
        }
},
{
        $project: {
                _id: 0,
                contentId: 1,
                contentMetaData: 1
        }
}]).pretty()
```

I'm new to Mongo. Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: I see `$map` in your post. Does it mean you can use 3.x mongo version ?

Comment: @Veeram `$map` is also available in 2.6

Comment: @Veeram - As Chridam mentioned, it's available in 2.6 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation.

`$map` in combination with `$setDifference` to extract `text_content` and `content_flag` array.

`$unwind` to `content_flag` document.

`$map` to keep the current values in `text_content` and `$map` in combination with `$setDifference` to filter the `children` on the criteria.

`$setUnion` to join back the `text_content` and `content_flag` array into `contentMetaData`

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        contentId: 1,
        text_content: {
            "$setDifference": [{
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$contentMetaData",
                        "as": "text",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [{
                                    $eq: ['$$text.name', "text_content"]
                                },
                                "$$text",
                                false
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        },
        content_flag: {
            "$setDifference": [{
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$contentMetaData",
                        "as": "content",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [{
                                    $eq: ['$$content.name', "content_flag"]
                                },
                                "$$content",
                                false
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$content_flag"
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 1,
        contentId: 1,
        "contentMetaData": {
            $setUnion: [{
                    $map: {
                        input: "$text_content",
                        as: "text",
                        in: {
                            "_id": "$$text._id",
                            "name": "$$text.name",
                            "attributes": "$$text.attributes",
                            "noOfChildren": "$$text.noOfChildren",
                            "positionIndex": "$$text.positionIndex",
                            "children": {
                                "$setDifference": [{
                                        "$map": {
                                            "input": "$$text.children",
                                            "as": "child",
                                            "in": {
                                                "$cond": [{
                                                        "$cond": [{
                                                            $eq: ["$content_flag.value", "true"]
                                                        }, {
                                                            $eq: ["$$child.name", "text_note"]
                                                        }, {
                                                            $eq: ["$$child.name", "text_description"]
                                                        }]
                                                    },
                                                    "$$child",
                                                    false
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    [false]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                ["$content_flag"]
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

**Update**:

`$map` in combination with `$setDifference` to extract `content_flag` array.

`$unwind` to `content_flag` document.

`$redact` to go through a document level at a time  and look for `name` field recursively and perform `$$DESCEND` and `$$PRUNE` on the criteria.

`$project` to format the final response.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        contentId: 1,
        contentMetaData: 1,
        content_flag: {
            "$setDifference": [{
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$contentMetaData",
                        "as": "content",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [{
                                    $eq: ['$$content.name', "content_flag"]
                                },
                                "$$content",
                                false
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$content_flag"
}, {
    $redact: {
        $cond: [{
                $or: [{
                    $eq: ["$name", "text_content"]
                }, {
                    $not: "$name"
                }, {
                    $eq: ["$name", "content_flag"]
                }, {
                    $and: [{
                        $eq: ["$name", "text_note"]
                    }, {
                        $eq: ["$$ROOT.content_flag.value", "true"]
                    }]
                }, {
                    $and: [{
                        $eq: ["$name", "text_description"]
                    }, {
                        $eq: ["$$ROOT.content_flag.value", "false"]
                    }]
                }]
            },
            "$$DESCEND",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        contentId: 1,
        contentMetaData: 1
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; I appreciate your efforts.

I tried your code, but I got an  _exception: invalid operator '$slice'_ in the shell. The use of `$slice` within the `$project` is not supported in Mongo 2.6.

Kindly refer :  https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/operator/projection/slice/ .

Moreover, I would suggest not using `$slice`, because we shouldn't assume the array length; it may vary in future. 

If you could just stick to the field names, that would be much helpful.

Comment: As per the updated answer, I'm able to get the desired `text_content`. But the rest of the fields present within `contentMetadata` is not getting updated.
I found that the `$setUnion` is only meant for merging two arrays.
Refer : https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion .

Since `content_flag` is just an object, this approach isn't working.

Comment: Looks like wrapping obj as `[]` only works from 3.2 version in `project` stage. Seems like it `[false]` is working in `setDifference`. Can you replace  `["$content_flag"]` with `{"$setDifference": [["$content_flag"], [false]]}` and see if it works ?

Comment: No, that didn't work as well. Instead of printing the entire object, it is printing  `"$content_flag"`.

Comment: Added an alternative.